# how change state of several elements after click on button with React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I use material-ui on React.js
I have several material-ui components in my main.jsx

> TextField

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      errorTextName: '',
      errorTextAge: '',
      errorTextCity: '',
      errorTextState: ''
    };
  }

<TextField
    id="name"
    errorText={this.state.errorTextName}
    onChange={this._handleErrorInputChange}
/>

_handleErrorInputChange: function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'name') {
      this.setState({
        errorTextName: e.target.value ? '' : 'Please, type your Name'
      });
    } 
  }
```

It works perfect when I type some text and delete it, but I need fire(show)

> errorText

only when I click on my button on all empty textfields:

```
<FlatButton
onTouchTap={this._handleClick}
label="I'm done lets go!"
/>

_handleClick: function(e) {
    this.refs.snackbar.show();
    //console.log(TextField.refs);
  }
```

So, how I can call TextField component methods from my FlatButton component?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a small project you can move the state of the TextField to a component that's a parent of both the TextField and the FlatButton. The child components can communicate to the parent through callbacks.

```
<Parent>
  <TextField onChange={this.change} />
  <FlatButton onClick={this.click} />
</Parent>
```

An other option if you don't want to pass down callbacks is to setup a global event system that components can listen to. I would recommend to only do this in small projects. In bigger projects it becomes really hard to debug when multiple components are firing and receiving events.

For bigger projects you most likely want to use a Flux implementation or some sort of global application state system.

Comment: Yes, I have same pattern, as you mentioned  `<Parent>
<TextField onChange={this.change} />
<FlatButton onClick={this.click} />
</Parent>`  only there are several TextField's `<Parent>
<TextField onChange={this.change} /> <TextField onChange={this.change} /> <TextField onChange={this.change} />
<FlatButton onClick={this.click} />
</Parent>` and I understand that I can create callbacks. Question HOW I can get all TextField in Parent, check all of them not empty and call onChange={this.change} after click on FlatButton?

Comment: If you are struggling with getting all the components under one parent you should use a global event system, flux or a global application state.